# How to pass authorization token in getURI(RCurl) package

Tags: rcurl

I am new to R. 
I am not able to send authorization token to an API via getURI(RCurl).

Example:
I am using following curl command to send an authorization token to an API

```
curl -H "Authorization:<token>" 'http://api.abc.com/def?id=243073'
```

Now I want to do the same via getURI(RCurl package) which I am not able to do. Please help me. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Some how <token> is not printed. Working curl command is  curl -H "Authorization:<token>" 'http://api.abc.com/def?id=243073'

Comment: Got the answer. One need to use option httpheader to pass Authorization token as follows.       getURI("https://api.abc.com/def?id=243073",httpheader = "Authorization:<abcd1234efgh>")